# Error when installing a GRASS addon!

Tags: grass-gis, linux, add-ons

I am trying to install r.inund.fluv on Linux to produce inundation maps but I am getting the below error. Note that I have a Fortran compiler.

```
GRASS 6.4.4 (newLocation):~ > g.extension r.inund.fluv

Fetching <r.inund.fluv> from GRASS-Addons SVN (be patient)...
A    r.inund.fluv/r.inund.fluv_62
A    r.inund.fluv/correction_from_path.f90
A    r.inund.fluv/clean_inundation.f90
A    r.inund.fluv/r.inund.fluv
A    r.inund.fluv/find_main_channel.f90
A    r.inund.fluv/README.txt
A    r.inund.fluv/r.inund.fluv.html
A    r.inund.fluv/Makefile
A    r.inund.fluv/2d_path.f90
Checked out revision 65521.
Compiling <r.inund.fluv>...
Makefile:4: /usr/lib64/grass-6.4.4/include/Make/Script.make: No such file or directory
Makefile:5: /usr/lib64/grass-6.4.4/include/Make/Module.make: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/grass-6.4.4/include/Make/Module.make'.  Stop.
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
```

Comment: You also installed grass-dev ??

Comment: Thank jejune, I couldn't find grass-dev but I am new to GRASS and not sure if I was looking in the right place. Is there a link to the grass-dev page? I am looking to test it on Windows first and the Linux (centos). I am using grass 6.4. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

since I'm from the debian/ubuntu universe it is called differently at centos/rhel...

have a look at http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Enterprise_Linux_GIS#How_to_enable_the_ELGIS6_repository

at centos it is called grass-devel-* (see http://elgis.argeo.org/repos/6/elgis/x86_64/)

remark: 6.4 is the old stable branch. I recommend 7.0 -> much more fun.

Comment: Hello, We have installed ‘grass-devel’ and all the dependencies. However it does not create or install an “include/Make” directory in /usr/lib64/grass-6.4.4/. Is there a package that provides that because it would appear as though those make files come from some place else. We are still getting the same error. Any thoughts or suggestions?